# How to exclude files/directories when running a Cucumber Rake task?

Tags: ruby, tags, cucumber, rake

I currently have two folders with different features within my scenarios folder:

```
features
  scenarios
    folder_1
      first_feature.feature
    folder_2
      second_feature.feature
```

Inside these features I have many scenarios that share some different tags

first_feature.feature:

```
Feature: One
  @tag1 @tag2
  Scenario: Scenario 1

  @tag3
  Scenario: Scenario 2
```

second_feature.feature:

```
Feature: Two
  @tag1 @tag4
  Scenario: Scenario 3
```

So here's the question:  I have a rake task which goes through my scenarios and runs everything with the tag @tag1. Right now that includes Scenario 1 in feature one and Sceanrio 3 in Feature 2.  Without changing any tags or scenarios, is there anything I can add to my rake task to tell it to ignore any tests in a certain file/folder?  In the example above, I would like my rake task to ignore any scenarios it finds in folder_2, so Scenario 3 will not run even though it has @tag1.

My current rake task:

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:all_tag_1) do |t|
  tags = '--tags ~@wip --tags @tag1'
  t.cucumber_opts = "--format html --out features/build_results/all_tag_1.html --format pretty #{tags} --format junit --out features/build_results/reports"
end
```

Part of the problem is that I have scoured the internet and Cucumber documentation and am unable to find anywhere that lists all of the valid options for cucumber_opts.  If anyone can even just point me in the right direction to find a list of the different possibilities, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:all_tag_1) do |t|
  tags = '--tags ~@wip --tags @tag1'
  t.cucumber_opts = "features/scenarios/folder_1 --format html --out features/build_results/all_tag_1.html --format pretty #{tags} --format junit --out features/build_results/reports"
end`

This command will only run scenarios from features/scenarios/folder_1 folder...

Comment: I appreciate the help with running a single folder, that will certainly be helpful.  As you can imagine though, this specific scenario is a bit of a simplification.  In reality there are 100 folders I want to run, but only a few I want to exclude.  I imagine I can play around with using your suggestion to run multiple folders or use wild characters, but what I am really looking for is an "exclude" command.

Comment: Okay, i got it. I think you can use tag feature (--tags ~@exclude) to exclude scenarios. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Ultimately this is what we ended up doing. However in the folder we want to exclude are ~25 features with 100s of scenarios.  Even if we add the tag at the feature level, that's 25 additional tags that need to be managed. It would be simpler if Cucumber had a way to include/exclude entire folders, but I'm beginning to think that just doesn't exist as a feature.  Thank you for your help :)